# How to convert xml to EDI x12 855 message in logic app?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, workflow-definition-language

How to convert xml to EDI x12 855 message in logic app?
i used Transform XML then i used Encode component there i get output as 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkRFk.png)

when i try to add decode component in logic app flow it shows an error like,
Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Decode_X12_message' inputs at line '1' and column '1535': 'The template language function 'base64ToString' expects its parameter to be a string. The provided value is of type 'Null'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#base64ToString for usage details.'. and i used "@{base64ToString(item()?[body('Encode_to_X12_message_by_agreement_name')?['Payload']])}" in code view of decode component.
How can i solve this and how can i generate EDi x12 855 from XML input? please provide me the workflow components to be used and workflow definition language for specific component.

Here is my logic app workflow
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qZFW.png)

Comment: i would like to get xml as input and i want to convert that to EDI x12 855 message. Please provide the logic app workflow for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `item()`, you only need:

```
@{base64ToString(body('Encode_to_X12_message_by_agreement_name')
?['Payload'])}
```

Comment: when i use compose before decode component. Now it shows an error like InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Decode_X12_message' inputs at line '1' and column '1535': 'The template language expression 'base64ToString(body('Encode_to_X12_message_by_agreement_name')?[outputs('Compose_2')])' cannot be evaluated because of property.

Comment: Same error? Try @xml(base64ToBinary(items('Encode_to_X12_message_by_agreement_name')?['Payload']))

Comment: It shows an error like:  Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Decode_X12_message' inputs at line '1' and column '1534': 'The template language function 'item' must not have any parameters.'.

Comment: Sorry, I copied your message, correct must be @body('Encode_to_X12_message_by_agreemen‌​t_name')?['Payload']

Comment: it shows an error like: the request content is null or empty in decode component. please help me how to create logic app flow to generate xml input into EDI x12 855

Comment: but in you image, you show the output of the encode component with the payload generated, what is the problem then?

Comment: i need payload in the form of BAK*00*AT*00*20180125~
REF*10*10~
PO1*02*5*****5 pens per bag**Pen~
PO1*03*6*****5 Pencils per bag**Pencil~
PO1*04*7*****5 scales per bag**scale~